# Visual Studio 2012 Git, How can I review all the files before merging them?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2012

I am using Visual Studio 2012 with Git plugin from Microsoft.

Using the Git plugin, I know I can *pull* and have the codes merged automatically, leaving only the conflicting codes for me to resolve.

But the fact that I do not know what is being merged makes me really worried. I would like to review ALL the files and manually accept/reject/manually merge the files.

Put in another way, I want to *fetch* and then review those files and merge them manually using Visual Studio.

Perhaps some instruction with screenshot would he helpful.

Answer (score -1):

I use the [Git Extensions](https://code.google.com/p/gitextensions/) VS add-on, and it allows that easily.

I tried the MS plugin, didn't care for it, and went right back to *Git Extensions*.

Comment: Right now the backend libgit2 library can only provide some of the git functions, so MS plugin's functionality is limited.